# Exception - unsupported compression type

Tags: apache-kafka

When ever we stop and removes kafka-logs and start the Kafka server am getting  `unsupported compression type`, Am not sure why am receiving this error,

Comment: Please share your full server.properties file, and any topic configs where you've set compression. Also, which Kafka version are you running and why are you manually deleting server files?

Comment: cricket_007 thanks for reply,
as a part deployment we doing this activity.
am using confluent kafka v1.2.0

Comment: What language? You mean librdkafka? That has nothing to do with the broker error